# Platform version and screen resolution statistics for Android tablet

Tags: android, tablet

where can I get some statistics about platform version and resolution [as given here](http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/platform-versions.html), but specific to tablets?

I basically need to know on which platform to develop for tablets. I've seen in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samsung_Galaxy_Tab) that Galaxy Tab has 2.2.1. So since this has been sold a lot, my guess is to develop for this version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at [Amazon's Best Sellers](http://www.amazon.com/gp/bestsellers/electronics/1232597011/) the top Android tablets are all around 10" and most of those are 1280x800. Unfortunately it looks like no one is using Google's tablet-specific [Honeycomb on their tablets](http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/platform-versions.html) (2%), so I'd stick with 2.2.x unless there are specific API's in 3.x or 4.x you need for your application.

<del>Up to date Android platform version distribution can be found at http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/platform-versions.html</del>

Comment: I already give this link in my question. I need to get tablet-specific data.

Comment: That's what I get for skim reading. Now I'm more determined to find the answer...